# How to call Stored Procedure from App_Code DataBase Class

Tags: c#

I  have a method in DataBase class that resides in App_Code which I use to call a Stored Procedure for Login, but when I make the call I get no error but my Login will not complete.

This is the DataBase Class:

```
    public class DataBaseClass
{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public DataBaseClass()
    {


    }

  public DataTable CallSP(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginUser", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "UserName";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "Password";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

This is the code I used to call for Login:

```
        DataBaseClass dbClass = new DataBaseClass();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dbClass.CallSP("UserName", "Password");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            boolReturnValue = true;
            Session["UserId"] = dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
            string updateLastLogin = "Update [User] SET LastLogin='" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "' where Id='" + Session["UserId"].ToString() + "'";
            dbClass.ConnectDataBaseToInsert(updateLastLogin);
        }
        return boolReturnValue;
    }
```

This is My Stored Procedure:

```
 CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoginUser]  (
@UserName nvarchar(20),   
@Password nvarchar(20) 
)  
 AS   

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 (
SELECT *  FROM [User]  WHERE Email = @UserName AND Password = @Password  
  )
```

Can anyone reproduce my code and tell me why my Login call could not work.

Comment: What is your message error?

Comment: By "Login will not complete", do you mean `dt.Rows.Count` is zero?

Comment: You are hard-coding the literal strings `"Username"` and `"Password"`. I assume you intend to use a variable there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do the following changes in the **CallSP** method:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = UserName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = Password;
```

Now appling more attention in your code I saw that your parameters are around quotes, so you were passing the literal strings "UserName" and "Password" instead the values.

With this changes you will pass the values from your parameters.

Sorry by my mistakes.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: @Crowcoder I fixed the comment, but I just disagree according call the dispose, the fill method doesn't do it automatically? as you can see in [Reference Source Fill Method] (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs,76ee69e4b70c4d1f)

Comment: Looks to me like it just Disposes the reader that is used to fill. 
DataAdapters are also Disposable - my point is this class is very leaky. It should implement IDisposable and release all the resources or not use them as fields and instead put them all within `using` blocks in the method.

Comment: Crowcoder, can you show example for your idea using the code above.